# Want to display the increment counter value on screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-ref

Without rerendering the component require to display increment value(changes.current) on screen. On click of button, the increment is happening, its displaying on console but not changing the value on screen.
We require to display the increment value(changes.current). I have also tried with `document.getElementById("p_id")` but it doesn't work.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  let changes = useRef(0);
  const changingValue = () => {
    changes.current++;
    //To print on console
    console.log("New Value: " + changes.current);
  };
  // Statement to check the rerendering happening or not
  console.log("rendering not happening");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* Button for click */}
      <button onClick={changingValue}>
        <b>Click me</b>
      </button>
      <p id='p_id'>{changes.current}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Expecting:
The updated value should show on click of button:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPOkF.png)`

Comment: Please refer Redux document for State management. https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Answer (score 2):

Mutating a React ref won't trigger a component rerender. React components rerender for one of the following 3 reasons:

1. React component state updated.
2. Passed props updated.
3. Parent component rerendered (because its state or props updated).

Updating some local state will trigger a rerender.

Example:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [changes, setChanges] = useState(0);

  const changingValue = () => {
    // Enqueue state update to increment the current
    // state value by 1, trigger rerender
    setChanges(c => c + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(changes);
  }, [changes]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button type="button" onClick={changingValue}>
        <b>Click me</b>
      </button>
      <p>{changes}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You could continue to store any value you like in a React ref, but in order to see any updated value the component ***necessarily*** needs to be rerendered so the updated UI can be flushed to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks Drew for quick response. But we are not allowed to rerender the page. Is there any other way we can display the updated value without rerrender.

Comment: @ArpitGoel Why are you not allowed to rerender the page? Why are you using React if that's a restriction? This is how React is designed and intended to be used. You update state or props and the app... ***reacts***... and updates the DOM.